# Checking if a variable which contains a string can be found in a file shell

Tags: string, file, shell, variables

```
if grep -Fxq $name1 test.txt
```

This does not seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: what's in $name1 and test.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
grep -Fxq $name1 test.txt  
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ... test.txt contains $name1 ...
else
    ... test.txt does not contain $name1 ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
match=`grep $name1 test.txt`
if [ -n "$match" ]; then
   echo found
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

it suffice:

```
 grep $name1 test.txt
```